# Pickaday2 not working properly in modal window

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datepicker

Getting issues in date picker.

If I use the picker in the bootstrap modal window. The year select drop-down list and month selection dropdown list not opening in firefox but it's working fine on chrome.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check with below code, this should work,

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};
```